# Is there a Python one-liner to grab the number of lines in a file EXCLUDING comments?

Tags: python, file, iterator

My file is a .txt file and all comments have no spaces before them.

I have a file with 10,000 lines that looks like this and I need to know the number of lines - the number of comment lines.

```
## something
## something
## something
12312312
123123
12312312
123123
123123
```

I found this one-liner that grabs the number of lines, but I haven't thought of a good way to grab the number of comments besides using an inefficient For Loop and a counter.

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(input_file))
```

Is there a Python one-liner to grab the number of lines in a file EXCLUDING comments?

Comment: That the solution is one line seems very important to this question. Can you explain *why* the solution must only be one line?

Comment: There is nothing particularly inefficient about a `for` loop.

Comment: @MrDoe, did you just change your question based on my answer?

Comment: @Robᵩ Yes, because I left out some details. Your solution 'num_lines = sum(not s.lstrip().startswith('#') for s in open('/etc/default/nss'))' does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution.

```
num_lines = sum(not s.startswith('#') for s in open('/etc/default/nss'))
```

Comment: That doesn't handle comment lines that don't start with a pound sign (i.e. there can be spaces before that.)

Comment: OP didn't ask for that. It isn't clear what his file format is, and whether comments have to start at first column or not.

Comment: `num_lines = sum(not s.lstrip().startswith('#') for s in open('/etc/default/nss'))`

Comment: @Robᵩ you're right, for some reason I thought OP was talking about Python source program lines.